# Devise LDAP Authenticatable not binding properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

For some reason, authenticating with Devise on my page doesn't seem to work, resulting in an Unauthorized 401 error. Going through the steps in net/ldap seem to bind just fine. I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Output from the server:

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"0uaLJJKobrDkn1mGDRP/RM6gIec+Wi7oykgWYuutsvk=", "user"=>{"login"=><login>, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 14ms
```

From ldap.yml:

```
development:
  host: <hostname>
  port: 389
  attribute: sAMAccountName
  base: <base>
  admin_user: <admin user>
  admin_password: <admin pass>
  ssl: false
  # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

From devise.rb:

```
config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
```

From testing on irb:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'net/ldap'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> ldap = Net::LDAP.new
=> #<Net::LDAP:0x141d19 @host="127.0.0.1", @auth={:method=>:anonymous}, @encryption=nil, @base="dc=com", @port=389, @verbose=false, @open_connection=nil>
irb(main):004:0> ldap.host = <hostname>
=> <hostname>
irb(main):005:0> ldap.port = 389
=> 389
irb(main):006:0> ldap.base = <base>
=> <base>
irb(main):007:0> ldap.auth <admin user>, <admin pass>
=> {:method=>:simple, :username=><admin user>, :password=><admin pass>}
irb(main):008:0> dn = ldap.search( :filter => Net::LDAP::Filter.eq('sAMAccountName', <login>)).first.dn
=> <login dn information>
irb(main):009:0> ldap.auth dn, <password>
=> {:method=>:simple, :username=><login dn information>, :password=><password>}
irb(main):010:0> ldap.bind
=> true
```

As you can see, the bind works fine through normal net/ldap testing, but it doesn't seem to work when I go through the actual Rails site for some reason, even if I replicate what the Devise module should be doing.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The authentication key is not :login but :username. it might fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having this issue, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577368/devise-ldap-authenticatable-devise-can-authenticate-via-ldap-with-test-script) gave me the fix I needed.