# devise_ldap_authenticatable + devise: can authenticate via ldap with test script, but doesn't work with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I can sign in using test code provided from net-ldap gem website, but same setting to login doesn't work with devise on Rails.

This is the server log when I try to log in on Rails using devise.

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Mar 22 10:53:39 -0700 2013
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign in", "authenticity_token"=>"bEmEPHuI8ob+O67hy0mpgGm12KzFnBNwRuhALAJzmCg=", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"1", "email"=>"somerandomeusername@corp.bigasscorporation.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "utf8"=>"✓"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'somerandomeusername@corp.bigasscorporation.com' LIMIT 1
  LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: mail=somerandomeusername@corp.bigasscorporation.com
  LDAP: LDAP search for login: mail=somerandomeusername@corp.bigasscorporation.com
  LDAP: Authorizing user mail=somerandomeusername@corp.bigasscorporation.com,OU=Users,OU=Users_and_Groups,DC=corp,DC=bigasscorporation,DC=com
  LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: mail=somerandomeusername@corp.bigasscorporation.com
  LDAP: LDAP search for login: mail=somerandomeusername@corp.bigasscorporation.com
DEPRECATION WARNING: an empty resource was given to Devise::Strategies::LdapAuthenticatable#validate. Please ensure the resource is not nil. (called from require at script/rails:6)
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 64ms
```

The below is some information about my environment

Ruby 1.8.7

Rails 3.2.13

Gems used

- gem "devise", "~> 2.2.2"
- gem "net-ldap", '~> 0.2.2'
- gem "devise_ldap_authenticatable", '~> 0.6.1'

LDAP configs

config/ldap.yml

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
  group_base: OU=Users,OU=Users_and_Groups,DC=corp,DC=somebigasscorporation,DC=com
  required_groups:
    - cn=Users,OU=Users_and_Groups,DC=corp,DC=somebigasscorporation,DC=com
    - OU=Users,OU=Users_and_Groups,DC=corp,DC=somebigasscorporation,DC=com
    - ["moreMembers", "cn=users,ou=groups,dc=test,dc=com"]
  require_attribute:
    objectClass: inetOrgPerson
    authorizationRole: postsAdmin

## Enviornments

development:
  host: xxx.corp.somebigasscorporation.com
  port: 3268
  attribute: mail
  base: OU=Users,OU=Users_and_Groups,DC=corp,DC=somebigasscorporation,DC=com
  # admin_user: cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
  # admin_password: admin_password
  ssl: false
  # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

config/initializers/devise.rb

```rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.ldap_create_user = true

  ...
```

The test code that works

```rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ldap'
require 'highline/import'

ldap = Net::LDAP.new
ldap.host = "xxx.corp.bigasscorporation.com"
ldap.port = "3268"
ldap.base = "OU=Users,OU=Users_and_Groups,DC=corp,DC=bigasscorporation,DC=com"
ldap.auth "somerandomuser@corp.bigasscorporation.com", "xxxXXXyyy"

if ldap.bind
  p "Success!!"
  p ldap
  p ldap.base
  p ldap.get_operation_result
else
  p "Failed!"
  p ldap.get_operation_result
end

# => "Success!!"
#<Net::LDAP:0x007fc393a22660 @host="xxx.corp.bigasscorporation.com", @port="3268", @verbose=false, @auth={:method=>:simple, :username=>"somerandomuser@corp.bigasscorporation.com", :password=>"xxxXXXyyy"}, @base="OU=Users,OU=Users_and_Groups,DC=corp,DC=bigasscorporation,DC=com", @encryption=nil, @open_connection=nil, @result=0>
"OU=Users,OU=Users_and_Groups,DC=corp,DC=bigasscorporation,DC=com"
#<OpenStruct code=0, message="Success">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed this in devise.rb

`config.ldap_auth_username_builder = Proc.new() {|attribute, login, ldap| "#{login}" }`

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this same issue, I found a slight problem with the `ldap_auth_username_builder` fix. I was also trying to set some authorizations on required attributes in the .yml file, and I was getting a lot of strange errors after `ldap.search` methods were being called by the gem. In particular, a lot of calling `.try(:first)` on a search that returned nil.

I ended up digging around in the gem's lib directory and tweaked some code for better logging. Turns out, when I added `config.ldap_auth_username_builder`, I was actually tricking the system to believe it found a record when it really wasn't. I wasn't able to specify attributes for these records because there was no record to begin with. If you guys are trying to do something similar, like check group membership or the like, I would suggest triple-checking that your `attribute` value in the `ldap.yml` file is set to a valid attr and that you're giving it the right information, so it can find what you need on the LDAP end.